# How I can export or connect to the SharePoint Excel file with multiple sheets and formulas all over the sheets if those formulas do not work

Tags: python, excel, sharepoint, powerbi, analytics

I need a help. I have a link to the shared file, the author gave me a permission to write and change it, but the problem is that even with those permissions some of the cells with formulas looks like #ref and when I delete the link and leave only formula it gives me #name. I need to find a way how to connect to this file and export needed data to do analysis. I tried to connect with power BI and with excel, but even with giving permission I still do not have access. I am pretty new to the SharePoint and power BI, but I guess that without permissions and right formulas I can’t do anything. My manager created this file and he can see all values and if he deletes links he also see value. I am thinking to try Python, but still without solving this problem I am not sure that I will be able to automize all updates

Power BI, Python, Excel queries, asked for permission, save file

Comment: What does the share link look like? Do you see the filename in the link? If it is a share link (without the filename) then that won't work. You will need to use the direct link. In Excel, go to File > Info, and at the top you should see a `Copy path` button. Use that link to import Excel.

Comment: Hi Sam, thank you for your response. The link looks like: ‘C:\Users\user_name\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\AddIns\MFC Calculator.xlam”! And then formula. I imported file and to the pover bi but still have empty cells where formulas should be

Comment: That doesn't look right. That link looks to be an addin. Is that the link the author shared with you? What's the SharePoint share link look like? (should start with https://...)

Comment: Sorry for misunderstanding, this is a path to the folder. This path is in the cell before formulas. So I have this link and then formela, and in SharePoint the output in the cell looks #CONNECT!, when I delete the path I see #NAME? And in the power BI these cells with Error. The thing is that I need those cells to work with and later to update. When the author open this file under his user he simply deletes path an sees the result

Comment: Share what the full formula looks like. It is clear an addin is being used which sits on their machine and not yours. You can get it to work on yours if you also include the addin on your machine. Once it is working, in theory PBI can then import it.

Comment: ‘C:\Users\user_name\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\AddIns\MFC Calculator.xlam”!calcperiodFC(selected cell; range of selected cells) And how can I include addin on my PC?

Comment: You will need to ask the author to send a copy of `C:\Users\user_name\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\AddIns\MFC Calculator.xlam` and you will need to place in the same relative place on your machine in your profile. Then it should work when you delete the link like the author does. Or find out which addin this is and install it on your machine.

Answer (score 0):

To connect to an excel file from Power BI, you need a specific link that you can get here :

- Open sharepoint/teams
- right clic on the file, open in excel app
- file, then information
- "Copy link to the file" (it should look like https://yourcompany-my.sharepoint.com/Documents/Classeur1.xlsx?web=1)
- keep only what is before the "?"
- Open power bi, then "Get data", then "Web"
- Paste your url (without ?web=1)
- If asked, log in
- That's it !